# How to compare Varchar fields in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, case, varchar

I have the following two tables, please see images

**Table1: predefined_attributes**
[image]

**Table2: product_detail**
[image]

I am trying to compare varchar fields, this is what i have tried

```
        `select product_id,category_id,color_name,style_name,
    case when color_name not in (select attribute_column_value from predefined_attributes where category_id=1 and attribute_column_name='color_name') then 1 else 0 END + 
    case when style_name not in (select attribute_column_value from predefined_attributes where category_id=1 and attribute_column_name='style_name') then 1 else 0 END as total_mismatch_count
    from product_detail where product_id in (123456,234567) and category_id=1;`
```

this is the query result, please see image

**query result**

[image]

actually the total_mismatch_count shoud return 0, but it shows 2 as total_mismatch_count.

i have checked the attribute_column_value from predefined_attributes table for color_name and style_name by using the below query, and i dont see any differences between the output and product_detail output.

```
`select attribute_column_value from predefined_attributes where category_id=1 and attribute_column_name in ('color_name','style_name') and attribute_column_value in ('Green','Pink','Basic','Classic');`
```

am i doing something wrong?, what is best way to compare the varchar so that the mysql query returns total_mismatch_count as 0 which is the correct result in this case?

*Note:* also i have updated **both** tables like this so that it doesn't have any spaces

```
    `update predefined_attributes set attribute_column_value=
    trim(replace(replace(replace(attribute_column_value,'\t',''),'\n',''),'\r',''));`
```

please help.

Comment: what output do you want ?

Comment: try using trim with both columns.  case when trim(color_name) not in (select trim(attribute_column_value) from predefined_attributes where category_id=1 and attribute_column_name='color_name') then 1 else 0 END

Comment: @JeanDoux, if both tables got same values, then the output should be 0

Comment: @Nikhil, i have tried yours, it still returns 2 as total_mismatch_count

Comment: check for difference in cases  i.e. lowercase uppercase ? copy the cell values color and style and paste in notepad and then check the difference.

Comment: @Nikhil, checked in notepad, both are same length and no differences in case.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it but something like that :

```
SELECT Count(*) as total_mismatch_count
FROM 
 predefined_attributes p_a
 LEFT JOIN product_detail p_d1 ON p_d1.attribute_column_name = 'color_name'
    AND p_d1.category_id  = p_a.category_id
    AND p_d1.color_name = p_a.attribute_column_value
 LEFT JOIN product_detail p_d2 ON p_d2.attribute_column_name = 'style_name'
    AND p_d2.category_id  = p_a.category_id
    AND p_d2.style_name= p_a.attribute_column_value
WHERE p_d2.category_id IS NULL or p_d1.category_id IS NULL
```

Comment: i have tried your query, it is also not giving expected result.